# Difference between gitlab "filter" and gitlab "search"?

Tags: gitlab

On GitLab, what's the difference between the Search widget and the Filter widget?

[image: widgets]

I noticed nothing happens when I type in the 'filter' box, even if I hit enter.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

On my GitLab 8.3 or 8.6:

- search will filter the project names, but also display other tabs (Issues, Merge Requests, Milestones), to launch the search on other topics.

[image: search]

- "filter by name" will only filter the project list.